# Excel 2013 - If cell contains specific text then display named range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Basically what the title says:

SO for example if cell A46 contains the word "Burn" then i would like to display my named range called "Burn_Treatment" on a separate page.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please share you code

Comment: I have no code sorry, i cannot figure out how to do it, i need to be able to figure out if a cell contains (not exact) a phrase, then display my named range

Comment: Okay can please be a bit more clear, what I understand is you are trying to find a value in your sheet and when you find it you want to capture the cell where you find the match, am I right

Comment: No. I have a list of instructions for the treatment of a burn - i have saved this range as Burn_Treatments. On a separate page there are several headings that are generated by doing other things. If one of the headings contains the word burn i would like to post my treatments for the burn (Named range: Burn_Treatments) under that heading. If it does not contain "burn" i would then like it to search for "Bruise" and if it contains bruise then copy the Bruise named range instead. so on and so forth for many other injuries, etc etc

Comment: Is it possible to post sample data with screen shots

Comment: Do you mean you have sheets with names as burn_..., bruise_... etc?

Comment: If you can have list of the ranged names in any place of excel, then you can use Vlookup values.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Chris. Please take a moment to read the guidelines in the Help Center about how to post Questions on this site. You need to provide a LOT more information IN your question. Please consider carefully how to describe your question so that others can understand what you have, *what you've tried*, *how* that did not work and what you expect. You can click the EDIT button below your question to add this information. Without it, no one can help you because they can't envision what it is you want!

Answer (score 0):

Use following:

```
=IF(A46="Burn",Burn_Treatment,"")
```

Comment: Sorry this doesnt work for me it just brings up #VALUE instead of my named range, i also need to be able to say if its not a burn then does it contain bruise then display an alternate named range called "bruise_treatment". needless to say there are several named ranges that will depend on the injury type